# How to turn objects in to HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do i get this :

```
<li>
 <div class='myClass1'>myData1</div>
 <div class='myClass2'>myData2</div>
 <div class='myClass3'>myData3</div>
 <div class='myClass4'>myData4</div>
</li>
```

from this code

```
var data1 = {"Columns":[{"Title":"Title1","HTMLClass":"g1_Title"},{"Title":"Title2","HTMLClass":"g2_Title"},{"Title":"Title3","HTMLClass":"g3_Title"}],"Rows":[{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]}]};



var GridRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var data = [], columns;

        // puts all the data in to a better structure (ideally the props would have this structure or this manipulation would be done on onReceiveProps)
        if(this.props.columns){
            for(var ii = 0; ii < this.props.columns.length; ii++){
                data.push({
                    class: this.props.columns[i].HTMLClass,
                    contents: this.props.Cell[i]
                })
            }
        }

        // Its best to map JSX elements and not store them in arrays
        columns = data.map(function(col) {
            return <div className= + {col.class}> {col.contents} </div>;
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <li>
                    {columns}
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var GridHead = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var cell = this.props.data.Title;
            var htmlClass = this.props.data.HTMLClass;
        }
        return (
            <div className={htmlClass}>{cell}</div>
        );
    }
});
var GridList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var header = this.props.data.Columns.map(function (columns) {
                return (
                    <GridHead data={columns} />
                );
            });
            var row = this.props.data.Rows.map(function (row, i) {
                return (
                    <GridRow columns={data1.Columns} cells={row.Cells}  key={i} />
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>{header}</li>
                {row}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});


var GridBox = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <GridList data={data1} />
        );
    }
});
```

The output right now is this

> In file "~/Scripts/Grid.jsx": Parse Error: Line 26: XJS value should
>   be either an expression or a quoted XJS text (at line 26 column 35)
>   Line: 52 Column:3

Comment: Try `'Cell2[i] = '<div className="' + this.props.columns[i].HTMLClass + '">{' + this.props.Cell[i] + '}</div>';`

Comment: If you'd like, I wrote a script that generates HTML from js objects: https://github.com/ndugger/HTMLBuilder.js you can at the very least, get an understanding of how I generate elements.

Comment: Just to address the error message, returned elements in react must be wrapped in div tags, that is why that error pops up.

Comment: Pleas see Edit, I have updated it and now I just get the HTML as a regular string in browser instead of as HTML. Is there anyother easier way to do this then adding libraries? I have tried to remove the strings so the reactJS components are used but this throws other errors.

Comment: Are you just trying to map out the column data? What is this.props.Cell?

Comment: Im trying to generate HTML based on column and row. columns[] contains CSSClass name and the cells[] contains string that are to be showed on the website within the html div element.

Comment: So `this.props.Cells` is actually `data1.Rows`?

Comment: this.props.columns is data1.Columns Class(Title and HTMLClass properties). this.props.cells is data1.Rows[x].Cells that is a array of strings. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: So what I like to do is to loop all the columns(in this case 3) and for every column I want to take out the HTMLClass for the div element and also the cell value from the same nr of element (1-3). So the outcom will be 3 divs with diffrent class and diffrent value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question initially asked was to do with just the `GridRow` component and nothing else I have not touched any other component.

Your main problem was you were assigning `className = + //something` in your GridRow component which isn't the correct way to assign. There were other errors like missing div tags.

**Better GridRow**

When the component mounts a `columndata` variable is created and is populated with formatted data using `formatData();`.

I do not recommend you do data formatting in this component (although it is doable). You should either format your data at a top level component and pass down formatted data or accept data in the correct structure.

My `GridRow` component to this:

```
var GridRow = React.createClass({        
  componentWillMount: function() {
      this.columndata = [];
      this.formatData();
  },

  formatData: function() {  // Formats prop data into something manageable
    if (this.props.columns && this.props.cells) {
            for(var ii = 0; ii < this.props.columns.length; ii++){
                this.columndata.push({
                    class: this.props.columns[ii].HTMLClass,
                    contents: this.props.cells[ii]
                })
            }
      this.forceUpdate();   // Forces a rerender
    }

  },

  componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {
      // If this component receives the props late
      if (!prevProps.cells && !prevProps.columns) {
        this.formatData();
      }
  },

  render: function() {
      var columns;

      // Its best to map JSX elements and not store them in arrays
      columns = this.columndata.map(function(col) {
          return <div className={col.class}> {col.contents} </div>;
      });

      return (
          <div>
              <li>
                  {columns}
              </li>
          </div>
      );
  }
});
```

I think it's important to note that you should avoid storing JSX elements in arrays.

I think you were basically on the money, except you were missing classname and div tags.

Comment: Thanks, but this also gives me syntax error. Pleas see my first post, I have updated it with all my JSX code. Thanks for the JSX element headsup.

Comment: @Banshee Okay try the above answer

Comment: Looks great, I will try it out as soon as I can. But why are you using duble i? (ii)

Comment: @Banshee it's easier to search for